# Portfolio or Case Study - for a Web Development Company

Tags: conversion, portfolio

This is about Web Development Company specializes in Web Application & Mobile Website Development.

On home page we intend to show portfolio (featured work we have done)... but what should we title them? I mean should we put it as Portfolio or Case Study? Essentially a portfolio or case study both of them are containing same information, with client problem definition, the solution provided by us along with the list of the technology / tools utilized and screenshots with notes.. and it also include a client review about the service. This also include innovative feature we've offered. Each project is having its dedicated page where all of this will get listed.

I'm just not sure what works best from visitor's point of view... I mean what helps in more conversion?

Portfolio or Case Study?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gathering that you are providing details as to what the clients problem was and your *unique* solution and how you leveraged the necessary technology/tools to accomplish this - along with screenshots, these definitely sound more like case studies...

Generally, a portfolio simply shows the what kind of work was done, and the end result.

Answer: Case Study

Comment: Yes, this point is valid and I'm sure it will be great to have this. Let's see how it works.. Once done, I'll be doing a A/B test to find out what is more effective?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is Case Study. I like it better than a Portfolio as it doesn't matter how it looks, it only matters why it looks like that.

To put it Zen-like, *"it's not the destination, the way what is important"*, especially in UX.

Comment: hmm.. yes I agree with you